# Zero padding numbers in org-num-mode?

Tags: org-mode, formatting

I like to working`org-num-mode` enabled:

```
 ** 4 Actions 
 *** 4.1 WAIT Lorem                      :visit: ▼
 *** 4.2 WAIT ipsum                        :uni: ▼
 *** 4.3 NEXT dolor                       :life: ▼
 *** 4.4 NEXT sit                          :yak: ▼
 *** 4.5 amet
 *** 4.6 consectetur
 *** 4.7 adipiscing
 *** 4.8 elit
 *** 4.9 sed
 *** 4.10 do
 *** 4.11 eiusmod 
 *** 4.12 tempor ...
```

However, when the number of subheading increases over 10, the alignment breaks from `4.9` to `4.10` (i.e. `sed` and `do` aren't aligned). It's very minuscule thing, but it's keep nagging me.

Is it possible to either:

- zero-pad the numbers from left (make `4.1` to `4.01`)
- or whitespace-pad the number from right (make `4.9 sed` to `4.9  sed` 2 whitespaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own format by defining a function, say `my/org-num-format`, and setting the variable `org-num-format-function` to it:

```el
(setq org-num-format-function #'my/org-num-format)
```

Do `C-h v org-num-format-function`. The default value of this variable is the function `org-num-default-format`. If you click on that, you'll get the doc string of the function itself:

```
org-num-default-format is a native-compiled Lisp function in
‘org-num.el’.

(org-num-default-format NUMBERING)

Default numbering display function.
NUMBERING is a list of numbers.
```

Click on the file name at the end of the first line and you'll get to the source code of the function:

```el
(defun org-num-default-format (numbering)
  "Default numbering display function.
NUMBERING is a list of numbers."
  (concat (mapconcat #'number-to-string numbering ".") " "))
```

You can use that as a model for your own function. For example, for two digit sections/subsections/subsubsections/..., you can format the numbers as follows:

```el
(defun my/org-num-format (numbering)
   "My own numbering function uses two-digit numbers (0-padded on the
left) for everything but the first number. It replaces the
built-in `org-num-default-format` function. `NUMBERING' is a list
of numbers."
   (concat (number-to-string (car numbering))
            "."
            (mapconcat
             (lambda (x) (format "%02d" x))
             (cdr numbering) ".")
            " "))
```

This converts the first number to a string without any formatting, but converts the rest of the numbers to two-digit strings with 0-padding on the left (the `"%02d"` format - do `C-h f format` for more information on possible formats) and with a `.` as separator.

You'll probably need to adjust the function to your taste and circumstances, but I hope the above provides the information necessary to do that.

Comment: As always thank you !!! This is exactly what I wanted. I got error `Wrong number of arguments: number-to-string, 4`. So I had to move closing brace `)`  to  `(concat (number-to-string (car numbering)) .......`  Now everything work Great !

Comment: Aaargh! I forgot to copy the tested function back into the answer. My apologies. Now fixed.